# C++ vector::begin not working

Tags: c++, vector

I am using following code to insert elements in vector.
I know about alternative methods, but want to know the logic behind.
Can anyone explain to me why the begin and end methods are not working?

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v[3];

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
        *it = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are not working as there is no such identifier as `v`. There is only an array of vectors which is `v[3]`. Your code does not compile. You don't want an array of vectors. You want a vector. You probably meant `v(3)` which is a vector constructor overload. Instead you declared an array of three vectors with `v[3]`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a vector, you have an array of vectors. An array does not have a `begin()` or `end()`. Try changing `vector<int> v[3];` to `vector<int> v;`.

Comment: Should possible be `std::vector<int> v(3);` to be what the OP probably wants.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd advocate leaving out the argument as there are some tripfalls with it, and reserving isn't that important until you get to performance-critical code.

Comment: Yes, I got your point now. That means each cell in this vector can have multiple vectors like this?

Comment: If you apply my suggested change in your code you will have one vector, and that vector holds ints. Right now you have an array of 3 vectors.

Comment: @dascandy It's pretty important if you want to immediately iterate over your elements ;)